# (VB) Spawning multiple enemies

Tags: vb.net

I'm currently making an arcade shooting game in Visual Basic which spawns enemies at the top of the form which move vertically downward toward the player. My current code spawns the enemy, but any attempt to add another 'enemyShip' to the 'enemyShips' array fails and hence, only a single enemy is spawned. Any help as to how to spawn multiple enemies would be appreciated. My current code is below:

```
Dim enemySize As Integer = 32
Dim enemySpawn As New Point(150, 0)
Dim enemyShip As New Rectangle(150, 0, enemySize, enemySize)
Dim enemyLoc As New Point(enemyShip.Location)
Dim enemySpr As Image = My.Resources.sprEnemy32x32
Dim enemySpeed As Integer = 5

Dim enemyShips(-1) As Rectangle
Dim intCount As Integer = 0

Dim g, bbg As Graphics
Dim backBuff As Bitmap

Private Sub frmMain_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    g = Me.CreateGraphics
    backBuff = New Bitmap(300, 300, Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb)
    bbg = Graphics.FromImage(backBuff)

    tmrSpawn.Enabled = True
    tmrRender.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub tmrSpawn_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmrSpawn.Tick
    SpawnEnemy()
End Sub

Private Sub SpawnEnemy()
    'Add enemyShip to index in array enemyShips
    'Add 1 to enemyShip's index so new rectangle is stored in the next index
    ReDim Preserve enemyShips(intCount)
    enemyShips(intCount) = enemyShip
    intCount += 1

    'Move newly created enemyShip vertically downward on the form 
    For Each Me.enemyShip In enemyShips
        enemyLoc = New Point(enemyShip.Location.X, enemyShip.Location.Y + enemySpeed)
        enemyShip.Location = enemyLoc
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub tmrRender_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmrRender.Tick
    bbg.DrawImage(enemySpr, enemyShip)
    g.DrawImage(backBuff, 0, 0)
    bbg.Clear(Color.Gray)
End Sub
```

Comment: Would it not be better to use a list rather than a re-dimmed array?

Comment: You must declare a new enemy every time you want to add one. You cannot just do it in the form class.

Comment: @Peterp - Yes probably, didn't consider that.